# Using Arabic packages in LaTex gives this error: (inputting `fleqn.clo' instead of obsolete `fleqn.sty'.)

Tags: arabic

I am working with LaTex, the script is working fine without the last 6 lines related to Arabic text, I tried many different Arabic packages the problem always same, the issue is:

```
Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H <return>.  
  \documentclass[3p,times,procedia]{elsarticle}
```

I am using the script below:

```
\documentclass[3p,times,procedia]{elsarticle}

\flushbottom

%% The `ecrc' package must be called to make the CRC functionality available
\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,
      linkcolor=blue,
      citecolor=blue,
      urlcolor=blue}

%% set the volume if you know. Otherwise `00'
\volume{00}

%% set the starting page if not 1
\firstpage{1}

%% Give the name of the journal
\journalname{Procedia Computer Science}

%% Give the author list to appear in the running head
%% Example \runauth{C.V. Radhakrishnan et al.}
\runauth{Author name}


%% Give the abbreviation of the Journal.
\jid{procs}

\usepackage{amssymb}

% if you have landscape tables
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
by the way I need all these package.

Answer (score 2):

If you load **fontspec**, you can't compile your document with pdflatex.
You have to compile it with **xelatex** or **lualatex**.

If you have only few words to insert in arabic, you can use **one** of these packages instead of fontspec :

- arabi
- arabtex
- babel

Comment: Hi, you can use into your editor the `{}` for the key words. I hope to help you.